# How to select an element from the drop down list in Java Selenium using Streams

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to select an WebElement from the list of WebElement using lambda streams. However, I am getting an error:

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException

This is the code which I am using. Please suggest where I am doing something wrong, and help me correct myself.

```
 public void selectOption(final String option) {
    clickOnDropDown.click(); // Clicking on this, a drop down will appear.
    dropDownList.stream()   // dropDownList is the List<WebElement>
            .filter(x -> x.getText().contains(option))
            .findFirst()
            .get().click();
}
```

Comment: take a look at https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/selenium-unable-to-select-drop-down-option-one-after-another

Comment: @JavaMan, Thank you. It would be more helpful if you help me in solving the problem by using streams